# JavaScript function to get DOM elements by any attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

I needed to write a function today in JavaScript that would return all elements based on a given attribute.

e.g retrieve all elements that have an id attribute in them.

The function I wrote for this is as follows:

```
function getElements(attrib) {
    // get all dom elements
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    // initialize array to put matching elements into
    var foundelements = [];

    // loop through all elements in document
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        // check to see if element has any attributes
        if (elements[i].attributes.length > 0) {
            // loop through element's attributes  and add it to array if it matches attribute from argument
            for (var x = 0; x < elements[i].attributes.length; x++) {
                if (elements[i].attributes[x].name === attrib) {
                    foundelements.push(elements[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return foundelements;
}
```

Looking at this, I am sure it could be written a great deal better. Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### querySelectorAll

First off, if you're only dealing with relatively modern browsers (basically anything above IE7), you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which is the fastest and easiest method to go about this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[' + attrib + ']');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc6Pq/

---

#### Sizzle

If you're stuck having to support IE7 and below, then you might as well just include the [Sizzle selector engine](http://sizzlejs.com/), since you're bound to be using some additional selectors in the future. Once you include the Sizzle script in your page, you could then just use it in a similar fashion to the native `querySelectorAll`:

```
Sizzle('[' + attrib + ']');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc6Pq/1/

---

#### jQuery

If you're already using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on the page, you don't have to use Sizzle separately, since jQuery has Sizzle incorporated within it. If that's the case, just use this:

```
$('[' + attrib + ']').get();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc6Pq/2/

Comment: This helped a great deal Joseph, thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too familiar with JS, so just three generic notes:

1. It seems to me that the `elements[i].attributes.length > 0` check is unnecessary because the statements inside the following `for` loop won't if `elements[i].attributes.length` is zero.
2. Consider creating local variables for `elements[i]` and `elements[i].attributes`. It would remove some duplication.

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       var currentElement = elements[i];
       var currentAttributes = currentElement.attributes;
       for (var x = 0; x < currentAttributes.length; x++) {
           if (currentAttributes[x].name === attrib) {
               foundelements.push(currentElement);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. It might be easier with jQuery: [find element by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/696968/843804).

Comment: I didn't realize that the check in your first note was unnecessary, I thought the interpreter might throw an error if it tried to loop something that wasn't an array. Your second note helped make my code more readable. Thank palacint!

Comment: @JohnH `element.attributes` is never an array; it's an array-like object. But even when there are 0 attributes, it is set to an object with a length of 0. So, the first comparison of the loop would return `false` without error.